# masking image with CSS

Tags: html, css, css-mask

I made a design like this

[image]

How to mask the background with css?

I have tried code like this

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask-image: url(https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GYiCod1.png), url(https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/GYiCQsM.png);
  -webkit-mask-position: bottom center, center center;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
}

.add {
  -webkit-mask-composite: add;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

The mask image I used are

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fg2k5.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmylJ.png

Can you guys tell me what is wrong in my code?
I know I can just import to png, but I tried to use css

Comment: you can use multiple background images nativly, don't use prefixes, take a look on first example here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Backgrounds_and_Borders/Using_multiple_backgrounds

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only need to consider one image which is the bottom part of your mask then use a simple gradient for the other part. You also don't need `mask-composite`. Simply adjust the size/position so that both mask don't overlap:

```css
.img-poster {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  -webkit-mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: repeat-x;
  mask:  
     linear-gradient(#fff,#fff)              top,
     url(https://i.ibb.co/5WvbqgG/zmylJ.png) bottom;
  mask-size:
     100% calc(100% - 30px),
     auto 30px;
  mask-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```

```html
<section class="section poster-container">
  <img src="https://imagejournal.org/wp-content/uploads/bb-plugin/cache/23466317216_b99485ba14_o-panorama.jpg" alt="" class="img-poster add img-responsive">
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

*SVG + filter solution*

The `SVG` solution for creating a serrated edge in images does not require the use of raster images of patterns with serrated edges.
Therefore, this SVG solution can be applied to any image and makes it adaptive.

Consider creating a jagged edge using the same image 2 times.
Filter is applied to the lower image and  because of this, it gets a little bigger.
The original image is superimposed on top and therefore the teeth on the edges become visible.
To leave the teeth only on the lower border, we cut off the unnecessary teeth with a mask on the lateral borders.

```css
.container {
 width:90vw;
 height:90vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 1800 900" >
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
        <rect x="100%" y="100%"  fill="white" /> 
      <rect x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" />
   </mask>
     <filter id="displacementFilter">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" seed="1"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="65" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
    </filter>    
 </defs> 
        
       <!-- The image is processed by a filter and therefore overall dimensions have increased due to the height of the teeth -->
   <image   filter="url(#displacementFilter)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/paWbQ.jpg.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
    <rect mask="url(#msk1)" x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" /> 
    <!-- The same original image, but without filters  -->
  <image x="0"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/paWbQ.jpg.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
</svg> 
</div>
```

*Another image*

```css
 .container {
 width:90vw;
 height:90vh;
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   viewBox="0 0 1800 900" >
 <defs> 
   <mask id="msk1"> 
        <rect x="100%" y="100%"  fill="white" /> 
      <rect x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" />
   </mask>
     <filter id="displacementFilter">
     <feTurbulence type="turbulence" baseFrequency="0.01 0.01"
        numOctaves="2" result="turbulence" seed="1"/>
    <feDisplacementMap in2="turbulence" in="SourceGraphic"
        scale="75" xChannelSelector="R" xChannelSelector="G" yChannelSelector="B"/>
    </filter>    
 </defs> 
        
       <!-- The image is processed by a filter and therefore overall dimensions have increased due to the height of the teeth -->
   <image   filter="url(#displacementFilter)" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYSe.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
    <rect mask="url(#msk1)" x="1700" y="0" width="50" height="900" fill="white" /> 
    <!-- The same original image, but without filters  -->
  <image x="0"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaYSe.jpg" width="1700" height="850" />
</svg> 
</div>
```