# How to blend two background images in css

Tags: css, image, background, opacity, blend

I have problem with blend two background images.
this's image 1 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cZfK.png)

And the second image [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgHWZ.png)

I want to blend them as curved background, the result should like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rH3oo.png)

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47829344/8620333

Answer (score 0):

Could you be a little more specific on what a curved background means? Also, you could blend the  two images by setting them

```
(tagname, class, id etc. {
background-image:url(enterimageurl1)
background-image:url(enterimageurl2)
background-blend-mode:blend mode to blend the images (you can go to https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-blend-mode.asp);
})
```

And your 2 images should be together!

Comment: NOTE: blend mode is the way the two backgrounds go together.